# What is considered an enemy unit?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was reading about Trundle's rework, and I noticed his passive is "Whenever an enemy unit near Trundle dies, he heals for 2% of their maximum Health." But what exactly is 'enemy unit' in this case? I think it includes enemy champions as well as enemy minions, but does it include jungle mobs as well? If it does, does that mean dragon and Baron are included? Seems a bit overpowered if all of those count as well...
I tried searching for the definition, but I can't find a clear explanation of what 'enemy unit' means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's minions, champs and jungle mobs, this is what gives Trundle his sustain while jungling (it's very useful).

See [this link](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Trundle/Ability_Details) for info, as a bonus you'll even get the regen if the enemy kills the unit (didn't think of that one myself!) so will trigger for neutral mobs as long as you're in range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you link a source?

Comment: What about sight? I minion can be in range but not in trundles vision will this still heal him?

Comment: I can't find a definitive answer about whether sight is required, but I think not. The wording implies that sight doesn't matter and the LoL wiki says it's anything within a certain radius. http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Trundle/Ability_Details

Answer (score 1):

Riot made a little mistake on that ability description. It actually means any unit that is not an ally, which mean : enemy champs, enemy creeps, enemy pets, neutral monsters, the drake, and Baron, the only exception being enemy structures (towers, inhibitors..(obviously the nexus)). However, as to counter the "over-powered" part of it, this passive has an innate "cap". You can't possibly have that much health recovered given the reasonably small range of this passive. The only exception, once again, being Nashor's death. That's a helluva heal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1 as it definitely adds to what was already answered. On a side note, the nexus is not so obvious, as it procs a lot of on hit effects and gives 50 gold to the champ that last hits it ^o^.

Comment: You're welcome. I mentionned the Nexus as being obvious since all units' health is fixed as soon as the Nexus is destroyed, which explains the "Invulnerable..Invulnerable..." appearing above damaged champs as the Nexus destuction animation is triggered.

Comment: haha, I didn't even think about that :P.